# Should we de-reference a pointer before passing by reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Years ago, I learned from my teacher from C++ course. He shows how to use pointer and linked list in C++:
[Not exact syntax]

```
//Declaration
Nodetype *head = new NodeType()...

//Call insertnode method: 
InsertNode(head, val1);

//The InsertNode function
void InsertNode(NodeType& head, int val1){}
```

As you can see above, we didn't de-reference "head". 
We use "InsertNode(head, val1);" instead of "InsertNode(*head, val1);"

However yesterday, when I learned smart pointer from the microsoft site:
They use "ProcessLargeObject(*pLarge);" instead of "ProcessLargeObject(pLarge);".

Should we dereference a pointer before pass by reference? or should we just pass by pointer without derefencing? 
Please advise

```
class LargeObject
{
public:
    void DoSomething(){}
};

void ProcessLargeObject(const LargeObject& lo){}
void SmartPointerDemo()
{    
    // Create the object and pass it to a smart pointer
    std::unique_ptr<LargeObject> pLarge(new LargeObject());

    //Call a method on the object
    pLarge->DoSomething();

    // Pass a reference to a method.
    ProcessLargeObject(*pLarge);

} //pLarge is deleted automatically when function block goes out of scope
```

.

Comment: Why have you tagged this as `C`?

Comment: Answers to this question will be somewhat opinionated. However, I generally follow the guideline that if it is okay to pass _null_ to the function then accept a pointer. If _null_ should never be allowed then accept a reference (i.e., make the caller verify the pointer is non-null and de-reference it).

Comment: @JamesAdkison: I worry that you may have misunderstood the question somewhat. It's not asking "should we pass-by-reference or pass-by-pointer?" It's asking "do I need to dereference a `T*` before using pass-by-`T`-reference?" and the answer is, of course, _yes_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for the clarification. That is indeed how I interpreted this: "Should we dereference a pointer before pass by reference? or should we just pass by pointer without derefencing? Please advise".

Comment: @JamesAdkison: The post title is _"Should we de-reference a pointer before passing by reference?"_. Maybe he hasn't been the clearest throughout the prose of the body (by uttering "pass by pointer" rather than "pass a pointer"), but I think it's clear enough with the code examples given (especially when reading his comment under my answer).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not disagreeing with you about my misinterpretation. I've also heard people generally say pass by reference even when they are talking about pointer parameters.

Comment: @JamesAdkison: Yeah - probably comes from not-C++ where "reference" isn't overloaded and is thus an acceptable general term for a "handle". Meh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As you can see above, we didn't de-reference "head". We use "InsertNode(head, val1);" instead of "InsertNode(*head, val1);"

That is an error, so the premise of your question is broken. You must have misremembered, or perhaps it is a typo in your course material. Or, maybe, your professor was simply mistaken.

You *have* to dereference `head`, because `InsertNode` accepts a `NodeType` (by reference), not a `NodeType*`.

In general, I can say that how you will use a linked list completely depends on the implementation. There is no "one way" to implement a linked list type in C++. You will have to read the documentation for the class you're using to find out how to use it properly.

FWIW, in actual production code, you would generally use `std::list` and be done with it.

Comment: Actually, my question is not really how to implement the linked list. But rather, in general, whether we should pass the pointer dereferenced or a pointer without dereference .   e.g; insertNode(head, val) or insertNode(*head, val).
Or AnyMethod(ptr, val)  or AnyMethod(*ptr, val).

void AnyMethod(Type &ptr, int val) {}

Comment: @Mr.Y: See the first two paragraphs of my answer.

Comment: Wow you guys type so fast lol
Oh I remember these notes were taken from my teacher (He hand-wrote it on the table :( )

So, I guess my teacher was mistakend.  The correct line should be: "InsertNode(*head, val1);"  

Thanks!

Comment: *Actually*, I think `InsertNode` should take `NodeType*&`, (a reference to a pointer to NodeType), and the *call* was correct.

Comment: @MartinBonner and others
Now you bring me to ask you a new question.

What is the difference between CodeA and CodeB below?: They are both syntatically correct and it seems both code will modify the original pointer "head".  Please correct me if I'm wrong
`code`
Code A: 
NodeType *head = new NodeType();
insertNode(*head, val);
void insertNode(NodeType &head, int val) {}
`code`


`code`
Code B: (Reference to Pointer)
NodeType *head = new NodeType();
insertNode(head, val);
void insertNode(NodeType *&head, int val) {}
`code`

Comment: @Mr.Y: Please ask new questions as such!

Answer (score 2):

It was probably a typo on the part of your instructor. If, as in the example you provide

```
void InsertNode(NodeType& head, int val1){}
```

the signature has a reference parameter, then passing in a pointer

```
NodeType *p = new NodeType;
InsertNode (p, 1);   // error
```

is ill-formed and shouldn't even compile.  Allowing a pointer would violate the strongly-typed nature of C++. If you have a pointer to an object that you want to pass in to such a function, you must dereference the pointer.

```
InsertNode (*p, 1); // correct
```